# Why are some key stretching methods better than others?

Tags: hash, passwords

I'm trying to understand why some key stretching methods are better than others. 
The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) presents 3 different key stretching methods:

> 1. A collision prone simple key stretching method:
>
>    ```
>    key = hash(password)  
>    for 1 to 65536 do  
>    key = hash(key)
>    ```
> 2. A better simple key stretching method. ("+" denotes the operation of concatenation):
>
>    ```
>    key = ""  
>    for 1 to 65536 do  
>    key = hash(key + password)
>    ```
> 3. Even better method with a salt:
>
>    ```
>    key = ""  
>    for 1 to 65536 do  
>    key = hash(key + password + salt)
>    ```

So, I was wondering why #1 is the weakest of the 3 while #3 is the strongest. My understanding is the following :

**The problem with #1**

```
A != B // 2 messages
hash(A) = hash(B) // It's possible in theory
hahs(hash(A)) = hash(hash(B)) // Same thing again…
```

So, it is easier to find 2 hash that gives the same end result, because if at any time in the hash chain they get the same result that result will not change afterward.

How #2 solves it :

```
A != B  
hash(A) = hash(B)  
hash(hash(A) + A) != hash(hash(B) + B)
```

Since only the last hash matter instead of every hash, we are less likely to get a collision.

**The problem with #2**

It is still vulnerable to rainbow table attack. That's why we need to use a salt like in #3.

Now… Is there a problem with #3, and/or what makes password hashing like PBKDF2 and bCrypt better key stretching methods than #3?

Comment: For what it's worth, I've removed those algorithms from the Wikipedia page. Wikipedia should not be encouraging amateurs to implement their own bespoke key stretching algorithms.

Comment: @StephenTouset Even if I know you should never implement your own cryptography, I found the example very useful to understand the concept.

Comment: Really? Your question here quotes the *entire* section I removed, asking for clarification of exactly why the given pseudocode has the properties claimed.

Answer (score 5):

On the non technical side, the main reason for choosing PBKDF2 or BCrypt is that they're commonly used. This means they have seen more analysis, reducing the risk of a dumb mistake and it's easier to defend them when somebody questions your choice.

What I dislike about your third variant is that it does not separate the different inputs. This isn't an issue if both `key` and `salt` have fixed length, but it's ugly. PBKDF2 has similar ugly but not practically relevant properties.

PBKDF2 has pretty similar properties to your third scheme. It has the additional feature of a variable output size, but it's so badly designed that this is more of a pitfall than an advantage. But you could always combine HDKF-Extract with your scheme if you need long outputs.

Bcrypt on the other hand has an advantage over both your scheme and PBKDF2 (used with common hashes like SHA-2): It's not friendly to GPUs. If you can afford 100ms of hashing on your CPU, the cost of a GPU based password cracker computing a hash is higher for Bcrypt than for PBKDF2. When an attacker uses an ASIC or FPGA, the advantage of bcrypt is smaller and you should consider using scrypt instead.

I also think that the need for including the password on each iteration of the hash (which you pointed out as a flaw in the first scheme) is often exaggerated. Even with a short hash like MD5 exploiting this is infeasible and becomes completely ridiculous once you use a 256 bit hash like SHA-256.

Comment: Also, check out [this](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3725/why-is-the-salt-used-only-once-in-pbkdf2-while-the-password-is-used-often) post that may help to explain the use of including the password for each iteration.